# Scrape 3 tables from multiple URLs with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am fairly new to web scraping and also to python. For my bachelor thesis I need data from rivercruise ships. I was able to write the following code, which is working on http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com.

There is also a second code which I wrote to get all the links for the ships I am interested in. I kindly ask for help, to combine those two codes in order to scrape the same 3 tables from all the links. This is my scraper, which works without any errors.

```
    from mechanize import Browser
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import lxml
    import csv

    url1 = 'http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/ama-waterways/ms-amabella-cruises/'

    mech = Browser()
    page1 = mech.open(url1)
    html = page1.read()
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
            
    ship_in = soup1.h1
    ship_in = ship_in.text
    ship = u' '.join(ship_in.split())
    u' '.join(ship_in.split())
    ship = [ship]
            
    h21 = soup1.h2
    h22 = h21.findNext('h2')
    h23 = h22.findNext('h2')
    h24 = h23.findNext('h2')
    h25 = h24.findNext('h2')
    h_y1 = h22.text
    h_y2 = h23.text
    h_y3 = h24.text
    itinerary1_header = u' '.join(h_y1.split())
    u' '.join(h_y1.split())
    itinerary2_header = u' '.join(h_y2.split())
    u' '.join(h_y2.split())
    itinerary3_header = u' '.join(h_y3.split())
    u' '.join(h_y3.split())

    table_1 = soup1.findAll('table')[0]
    table_2 = soup1.findAll('table')[1]
    table_3 = soup1.findAll('table')[2]

    rows_1 = table_1.findAll("tr")
    rows_2 = table_2.findAll("tr")
    rows_3 = table_3.findAll("tr")


    for row_1 in rows_1:
            cells_1 = row_1.findAll('td')
                    
            list_1 = table_1.findAll('li')
            decks = str(list_1[0].get_text()).split(':')
            cabin = str(list_1[1].get_text()).split(':')
            cabin_number = str(list_1[2].get_text()).split(':')
            
            list_key = ''.join(list(decks[0] + '|' + cabin[0] + '|' + cabin_number[0]))
            list_value = ''.join(list(decks[1] + '|' + cabin[1] + '|' + cabin_number[1]))
            list_key = list_key.split('|')
            list_value = list_value.split('|')
                    
            try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
                    col1_1 = str(cells_1[0].get_text()).split('\n') # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
                    col2_1 = str(cells_1[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                    col3_1  = str(cells_1[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                    col4_1  = str(cells_1[3].get_text()).split('\n')
            except:
                    continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error
            
            keys_1 = ['ship'] + col1_1 + col3_1 + list_key
            values_1 = ship + col2_1 + col4_1 + list_value
            dict_1 = dict(zip(keys_1, values_1))
            
            with open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/details/details_'+ ship_in + '.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
                    w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict_1.keys())
                    w.writeheader()
                    w.writerow(dict_1)
                    f.close()
            
    list_of_rows_2=[]
    for row_2 in rows_2:
            cells_2 = row_2.find_all("td")        
            list_of_cells_2 = [itinerary1_header]
            
            try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
                    date1_2 = str(cells_2[0].get_text()) # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
                    itinerary2_2 = str(cells_2[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                    price3_2 = str(cells_2[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                    list_of_cells_2.append(date1_2)
                    list_of_cells_2.append(itinerary2_2)
                    list_of_cells_2.append(price3_2)
            except:
                        
                    continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error
            list_of_cells_2.append(ship)
            list_of_rows_2.append(list_of_cells_2)
            
            outfile_2 = open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/itinerary1/itinerary1_'+ ship_in + '.csv', "wb")
            writer = csv.writer(outfile_2, delimiter='|')
            writer.writerows(list_of_rows_2)      
            outfile_2.close()
            
              
            
    list_of_rows_3=[]
    for row_3 in rows_3:
            cells_3 = row_3.find_all("td")        
            list_of_cells_3 = [itinerary2_header]
            
            try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
                    date1_3 = str(cells_3[0].get_text()) # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
                    itinerary2_3 = str(cells_3[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                    price3_3 = str(cells_3[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                    list_of_cells_3.append(date1_3)
                    list_of_cells_3.append(itinerary2_3)
                    list_of_cells_3.append(price3_3)
            except:
                        
                    continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error
            list_of_cells_3.append(ship)
            list_of_rows_3.append(list_of_cells_3)
                            
            outfile_3 = open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/itinerary2/itinerary2_'+ ship_in + '.csv', "wb")
            writer = csv.writer(outfile_3, delimiter='|')
            writer.writerows(list_of_rows_3)
            outfile_3.close()        
                
    print "check out the data!"
```

Here is the second code - which also works and gets all links and stores them in the `page_array` variable.

```
   from mechanize import Browser
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import lxml
   from lxml import html
   import csv
   import requests


   page_array = []

   mech = Browser()
   url = 'http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/'
   page = mech.open(url)
   html = page.read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
   table1 = soup.table #Ocean Cruise
   table2 = table1.findNext('table')#River Cruise
   pages = table2.findAll('a')
           

   for page in pages:
         page_array.append(page.get('href').replace('http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/', ''))
```

What is a proper python method to combine those codes and get all the data I need. Your help would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from lxml import html
import csv
import requests


page_array = []

mech = Browser()
url = 'http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/'
page = mech.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
table1 = soup.table #Ocean Cruise
table2 = table1.findNext('table')#River Cruise
pages = table2.findAll('a')


for page in pages:
     page_array.append(page.get('href'))


for page in page_array:

    mech = Browser()
    page1 = mech.open(page)
    html = page1.read()
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    ship_in = soup1.h1
    ship_in = ship_in.text
    ship = u' '.join(ship_in.split())
    u' '.join(ship_in.split())
    ship = [ship]

    h21 = soup1.h2
    h22 = h21.findNext('h2')
    h23 = h22.findNext('h2')
    h24 = h23.findNext('h2')
    h25 = h24.findNext('h2')
    h_y1 = h22.text
    h_y2 = h23.text
    h_y3 = h24.text
    itinerary1_header = u' '.join(h_y1.split())
    u' '.join(h_y1.split())
    itinerary2_header = u' '.join(h_y2.split())
    u' '.join(h_y2.split())
    itinerary3_header = u' '.join(h_y3.split())
    u' '.join(h_y3.split())

    table_1 = soup1.findAll('table')[0]
    table_2 = soup1.findAll('table')[1]
    table_3 = soup1.findAll('table')[2]

    rows_1 = table_1.findAll("tr")
    rows_2 = table_2.findAll("tr")
    rows_3 = table_3.findAll("tr")


    for row_1 in rows_1:
            cells_1 = row_1.findAll('td')

            list_1 = table_1.findAll('li')
            decks = str(list_1[0].get_text()).split(':')
            cabin = str(list_1[1].get_text()).split(':')
            cabin_number = str(list_1[2].get_text()).split(':')

            list_key = ''.join(list(decks[0] + '|' + cabin[0] + '|' + cabin_number[0]))
            list_value = ''.join(list(decks[1] + '|' + cabin[1] + '|' + cabin_number[1]))
            list_key = list_key.split('|')
            list_value = list_value.split('|')

            try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
                    col1_1 = str(cells_1[0].get_text()).split('\n') # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
                    col2_1 = str(cells_1[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                    col3_1  = str(cells_1[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                    col4_1  = str(cells_1[3].get_text()).split('\n')
            except:
                    continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error

            keys_1 = ['ship'] + col1_1 + col3_1 + list_key
            values_1 = ship + col2_1 + col4_1 + list_value
            dict_1 = dict(zip(keys_1, values_1))

            with open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/details/details_'+ ship_in + '.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
                    w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict_1.keys())
                    w.writeheader()
                    w.writerow(dict_1)
                    f.close()

    list_of_rows_2=[]
    for row_2 in rows_2:
            cells_2 = row_2.find_all("td")        
            list_of_cells_2 = [itinerary1_header]

            try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
                    date1_2 = str(cells_2[0].get_text()) # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
                    itinerary2_2 = str(cells_2[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                    price3_2 = str(cells_2[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                    list_of_cells_2.append(date1_2)
                    list_of_cells_2.append(itinerary2_2)
                    list_of_cells_2.append(price3_2)
            except:

                    continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error
            list_of_cells_2.append(ship)
            list_of_rows_2.append(list_of_cells_2)

            outfile_2 = open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/itinerary1/itinerary1_'+ ship_in + '.csv', "wb")
            writer = csv.writer(outfile_2, delimiter='|')
            writer.writerows(list_of_rows_2)      
            outfile_2.close()



    list_of_rows_3=[]
    for row_3 in rows_3:
            cells_3 = row_3.find_all("td")        
            list_of_cells_3 = [itinerary2_header]

            try: #we are using "try" because the table is not well formatted. This allows the program to continue after encountering an error.
                    date1_3 = str(cells_3[0].get_text()) # This structure isolate the item by its column in the table and converts it into a string.
                    itinerary2_3 = str(cells_3[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                    price3_3 = str(cells_3[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                    list_of_cells_3.append(date1_3)
                    list_of_cells_3.append(itinerary2_3)
                    list_of_cells_3.append(price3_3)
            except:

                    continue #This tells the computer to move on to the next item after it encounters an error
            list_of_cells_3.append(ship)
            list_of_rows_3.append(list_of_cells_3)

            outfile_3 = open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/itinerary2/itinerary2_'+ ship_in + '.csv', "wb")
            writer = csv.writer(outfile_3, delimiter='|')
            writer.writerows(list_of_rows_3)
            outfile_3.close()        

    print "check out the data!"
```

This is now my edited version. The output are 3 .csv files. And then it throws an error:

check out the data!

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/ship scraper editedt.py", line 55, in 
table_3 = soup1.findAll('table')[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

However I do not get the error, when running only a single url (url1 = 'http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/ama-waterways/ms-amabella-cruises/').

**Edit:**

```
   from mechanize import Browser
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import lxml
   from lxml import html
   import csv
   import requests

   base_url = 'http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/'

   def get_links():
          links_array = []
          mech = Browser()
          mech.set_handle_robots(False)
          page = mech.open(base_url)
          html = page.read()
          soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
          tables = soup.findAll('table') 
          
          for table in tables:
              links = tables[1].findAll('a')

          for link in links:
                links_array.append(link.get('href').replace('http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/', ''))

          return links_array


   def get_headings(url):
       mech = Browser()
       mech.set_handle_robots(False)
       page = mech.open(url)
       html = page.read()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
       headings = soup.findAll('h2') 
       return headings

       
   get_links()
   urls = [base_url + link for link in get_links()]

   for url in urls:
       mech = Browser()
       mech.set_handle_robots(False)
       
       try:
           page = mech.open(url)
       except:
           continue
       html = page.read()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

       tables = soup.findAll('table')
       
       ship_in = soup.h1
       ship_in = ship_in.text
       ship = u' '.join(ship_in.split())
       u' '.join(ship_in.split())
       ship = [ship]
       try:
           details = tables[0]
       except:
           continue
       rows_1 = details.findAll("tr")  

       for row_1 in rows_1:
               cells_1 = row_1.findAll('td')
               try:
                      list_1 = details.findAll('li')
                      decks = list_1[0].text.encode('utf8').split(':')
                      cabin = list_1[1].text.encode('utf8').split(':')
                      cabin_number = list_1[2].text.encode('utf8').split(':')
                      list_key = ''.join(list(decks[0] + '|' + cabin[0] + '|' + cabin_number[0]))
                      list_value = ''.join(list(decks[1] + '|' + cabin[1] + '|' + cabin_number[1]))
                      list_key = list_key.split('|')
                      list_value = list_value.split('|')

                      try: 
                              col1_1 = str(cells_1[0].get_text()).split('\n')
                              col2_1 = str(cells_1[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                              col3_1  = str(cells_1[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                              col4_1  = str(cells_1[3].get_text()).split('\n')
                      except:
                              continue

                      keys_1 = ['ship'] + col1_1 + col3_1 + list_key
                      values_1 = ship + col2_1 + col4_1 + list_value
                      dict_1 = dict(zip(keys_1, values_1))
                      with open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/details/details_'+ ship_in + '.csv', 'wb') as f:
                             w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict_1.keys())
                             w.writeheader()
                             w.writerow(dict_1)
                             f.close()                  
       
               except:                   
                      if not list_1:
                             list_of_rows_1=[]
                             for row_1 in rows_1:
                                    cells_1 = row_1.findAll('td')

                                    try: 
                                            col1_1 = cells_1[0].text.encode('utf8').split(':') 
                                            col2_1 = cells_1[1].text.encode('utf8').split(':')
                                            col3_1 = cells_1[2].text.encode('utf8').split(':')
                                            col4_1 = cells_1[3].text.encode('utf8').split(':')
                                            list_of_cells_1.append(col1_1)
                                            list_of_cells_1.append(col2_1)
                                            list_of_cells_1.append(col3_1)
                                            list_of_cells_1.append(col4_1)
                                    except:
                                            continue 
                                    list_of_rows_1.append(list_of_cells_1)

                                    outfile_1 = open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/details/details_'+ ship_in + '.csv', "wb")
                                    writer = csv.writer(outfile_1, delimiter='|')
                                    writer.writerows(list_of_rows_1)      
                                    outfile_1.close()
                      else:
                          continue
       try:
              itineray1 = tables[1]
              rows_2 = itineray1.findAll("tr")
              list_of_rows_2=[]
              for row_2 in rows_2:
                      cells_2 = row_2.find_all("td")
                      list_of_cells_2 = [get_headings(url)[2].text]

                      try:
                              date1_2 = str(cells_2[0].get_text())
                              itinerary2_2 = str(cells_2[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                              price3_2 = str(cells_2[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                              list_of_cells_2.append(date1_2)
                              list_of_cells_2.append(itinerary2_2)
                              list_of_cells_2.append(price3_2)
                      except:
                              continue
                      list_of_cells_2.append(ship)
                      list_of_rows_2.append(list_of_cells_2)

                      outfile_2 = open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/itinerary1/itinerary1_'+ ship_in + '.csv', "wb")
                      writer = csv.writer(outfile_2, delimiter='|')
                      writer.writerows(list_of_rows_2)      
                      outfile_2.close()      
                      
       except:
              continue

       try:
              itineray2 = tables[2]
              list_of_rows_3=[]
              for row_3 in rows_3:
                      cells_3 = row_3.find_all("td")        
                      list_of_cells_3 = [get_headings(url)[3].text]

                      try:
                              date1_3 = str(cells_3[0].get_text())
                              itinerary2_3 = str(cells_3[1].get_text()).split('\n')
                              price3_3 = str(cells_3[2].get_text()).split('\n')
                              list_of_cells_3.append(date1_3)
                              list_of_cells_3.append(itinerary2_3)
                              list_of_cells_3.append(price3_3)
                      except:

                              continue
                      list_of_cells_3.append(ship)
                      list_of_rows_3.append(list_of_cells_3)

                      outfile_3 = open('Z:/Cruiseshipschedule/itinerary2/itinerary2_'+ ship_in + '.csv', "wb")
                      writer = csv.writer(outfile_3, delimiter='|')
                      writer.writerows(list_of_rows_3)
                      outfile_3.close()
       except:
              continue
       print "check out the data!"
```

Thanks for all the support! The code works - which means I get data. But strange wise for some ships it takes only a few itineraries. I can't find the mistake in my code. Python doesn't throw a error.

While scraping I saw that a few urls do not have exactly the same structure of tables. That is why I put try and except to avoid stopping the script.

I would really appreciate some thoughts.

Comment: At the bottom of your first program, paste your second program?

Answer (score 1):

```
#Second program here:
...
...
page_array = [....]

for page in page_array:

    mech = Browser()
    page1 = mech.open(page)

   #...The rest of the 1st program here
```

Another option would be to convert your second program to a function:

```
   from mechanize import Browser
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import lxml
   from lxml import html
   import csv
   import requests

def get_links(url):
       links_array = []

       mech = Browser()
       #url = 'http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/'
       page = mech.open(url)
       html = page.read()
       soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
       table1 = soup.table #Ocean Cruise
       table2 = table1.findNext('table')#River Cruise
       links = table2.findAll('a')


       for link in links:
             links_array.append(link.get('href').replace('http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/', ''))

      return links_array  #<****HERE
```

Then in the first program, you would import the file that contains your second program:

```
import second_prog 

url = 'http://www.cruiseshipschedule.com/ama-waterways/ms-amabella-cruises/'
mech = Browser()

for link in second_prog.get_links(url):
    page = mech.open(link)
    #Continue with first program here
```

And, if you want to keep everything in the same file, then you could move the function in your second program into your first program--which would mean you wouldn't need the import statement anymore.

**Edit:**

Does any of the following code have anything to do with your error:

```
ship_in = soup1.h1
ship_in = ship_in.text
ship = u' '.join(ship_in.split())
u' '.join(ship_in.split())
ship = [ship]

h21 = soup1.h2
h22 = h21.findNext('h2')
h23 = h22.findNext('h2')
h24 = h23.findNext('h2')
h25 = h24.findNext('h2')
h_y1 = h22.text
h_y2 = h23.text
h_y3 = h24.text
itinerary1_header = u' '.join(h_y1.split())
u' '.join(h_y1.split())
itinerary2_header = u' '.join(h_y2.split())
u' '.join(h_y2.split())
itinerary3_header = u' '.join(h_y3.split())
u' '.join(h_y3.split())
```

Let's see:

```
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

#Code above here

table_1 = soup1.findAll('table')[0]
table_2 = soup1.findAll('table')[1]
table_3 = soup1.findAll('table')[2]
```

Calculating table_1 does not reference anything that was removed.
Calculating table_2 does not reference anything that was removed.
Calculating table_3 does not reference anything that was removed.

So, you make a copy of your program, and you delete that whole section. Then you try to figure out what went wrong.  The process of deleting code to isolate a problem is called *debugging* code.

Next, why should you make BS go to the trouble--and the time--of searching through the whole html page 3 times to get all the tables?

```
table_1 = soup1.findAll('table')[0]
table_2 = soup1.findAll('table')[1]
table_3 = soup1.findAll('table')[2]
```

Every time you write `soup1.findAll('table')`, BS has to search through the whole html page to find all the `<table>` tags.

Instead, you can search just once:

```
 tables = soup1.findAll('table')

 table1 = tables[0]
 table2 = tables[1]
 table3 = tables[2]
```

Making python retrieve an element from a list is very fast--much faster than making BS search through an entire web page hunting for all the `<table>` tags.

Next, whenever you find yourself writing variables with names:

```
 table1
 table2
 table3
```

and they only differ by a number, you need to STOP what you are doing--and use a list instead.  In this case, you already have a list: `tables`, and the elements inside `tables` already have the names `tables[0], tables[1], tables[2]`, etc., so you don't need to create the variables `table1, table2, table3`.   In fact, you don't even have to refer to the elements of `tables` by the names `tables[0], tables[1], tables[2]`--instead you can use a `for loop` to step through all the tables:

```
for table in tables:

    #Do something with the table variable
```

That has two advantages:

1) You don't have to write all the names `tables[0], tables[1], tables[2]` in your code.  What if you had to examine 1,000 tables?  Are you really going to write:

```
tables[0] = ...
tables[1] = ...
...
...
<an hour later>
tables[999] = ...
```

2) The second advantage of using a for loop is that you only have to write the code that processes a table ONCE, and the `for loop` will apply the code to each table in the `tables` list.

If `tables` has more table tags than you want to examine, then you can write:

```
first_three = tables[:3]
```

But note that if tables only has two tables, then `first_three` will only contain two tables.  That *can* be an advantage: a for loop doesn't need to know how many table tags are in the tables list--a for loop will blindly process all the elements in the list you give it, no matter how many tables are in the list.

Finally, your error states:

```
table_3 = soup1.findAll('table')[2] IndexError: list index out of range
```

That is the same error you would get if you did this:

```
data = ['a', 'b']
print(data[2])
```

That means that findAll() found less than 3 tables on the page.  How do you fix that?  If the page doesn't contain three tables then it doesn't contain three tables.  You can process only the tables a page contains with a max of three, like this:

```
target_tables = tables[:3]

for table in target_tables:

    #Do stuff here
```

Comment: I edited the code and get an error now. The error is shown in my edit. Further help would be apreciated.

Comment: @7stud   thanks for your help! It was easy to follow along. Now I wrote my code completely new. I get data - but not all. Pls. see my edit.

Comment: @Mr.Elfman, *While scraping I saw that a few urls do not have exactly the same structure of tables.* Can you post an example of the two pages and where they differ?  Searching by position on a page makes your code very brittle. If you can it's better to locate the tags you are interested in by id, name, or class.